# How can I count the number grater then 10 in the first array?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I would like to count how many numbers in `RandomArray` are greater than 10

For example, if `RandomArray` contained `[1, 5, 9, 11, 18, 23]` it would return **3**

```
for(i=1; i<=9; i++) {
    RandomArray[i] = r.nextInt((upper + 1) - lower) + lower;
    System.out.println(i + 1 + " the random  number is : "  +RandomArray[i]);
```

Comment: You want to count how many numbers in `RandomArray` are greater than 10 ?

Comment: yes, I want count those number are grater then 10.

Comment: Please show us some code and ask specific questions about concepts you do not unterstand. Otherwise, we will assume that this is some homework you want to get done for you and nobody will answer.

Comment: I try with if statement but it count all numbers.

Comment: @Turing85 is right. Do show the code with if statement if you don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Ahmed Please post your attempt. Maybe we can figure out, what you do not understand and explain it to you.

Comment: In a user friendly Java program you should 1 create 10 random integer numbers between 1 and 20 (included) and store these numbers in an appropriate array.

2.output the array to the screen. 

3.Increase all numbers by the number 5 and store the results in a second array.


4.output the second array to the screen. 5. count all numbers in the first array which are greater than 10 and show the result.


5.Calculate the duplication of the amount of numbers greater 10 in a method and show the result in an output method.                                               || I stuck at number 5||

Comment: @Ahmed This is the exercise text. But that does not help a bit. Please post your attempt of solving it. We will not solve it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 solution. Make a stream from the array, filter to keep values greater than 10 and count them :

```
long count = Arrays.stream(RandomArray).filter(n -> n > 10).count();
```

Comment: I see what you did there ;) Shall we bet his assignment has the topic `if`-statments?

Comment: Are you betting for or against ? I am betting for. But writing code with Java 8 streams is lots of fun for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `counter`.

```
int counter = 0;
for(i=1; i<=9; i++) {
    RandomArray[i] = r.nextInt((upper + 1) - lower) + lower;
    if (RandomArray[i] > 10) {
      counter++;
     }
}
```

Comment: You know... SO is not a place where someone posts a problem and you post code, that solves this problem.

Comment: @Turing85 He mentioned that he tried if-statements which did not work. Thus, I took my time to show him how to structure the statement. Furthermore, the simplicity of the question does not require any further hints.

Comment: You haven't even seen his `if`-statement and therefore do not know, how he tried to solve the problem. But why should you care? You got your reputation...

Comment: @Turing85 Please, calm down. Read my earlier comment again and understand it properly. I do not have see how he structured it, because he obviously did it wrong. I showed him the correct way by using his own code for him to learn how it works.